# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CRON jobs setup

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron

I have been struggling to setup some CRON jobs on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've setup the rest of the app I'm deploying just fine, but really stuck at this point.

I have created a cron.yaml file and then created a new worker environment inside the app. This worker will load the YAML file, and it will run the CRON jobs. However, it looks for PHP files (the targets of the jobs) inside the new worker environment and they are obviously not there, but rather on the main web environment. So everything comes back with a 404 error in the logs.

YAML will not run on the web server environment, so the solution is not as simple as moving it there (unless there is some trick someone knows).

Is there a simple way to use the YAML files to run CRON jobs on the production environment? Am I missing something? This is my first time using this platform and I am used to these things being rather simple; usually setup on the host somewhere in a minute and that's all. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I've been using a workaround where I run a worker environment that calls PHP files which in turn use file_get_contents(); to call publicly accessible PHP files on the production environment. Seems to work, but I've also kept this EB setup to be a single instance for now since I don't know what happens if this was a multi-instance setup.

If anyone wishes to use this workaround, here is example code for your worker environment:

cron.yaml

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "your_process_name_here"
   url: "/process_file.php"
   schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
```

process_file.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://your_public_URL.com/actual_php_file.php");
?>
```

The above two files, after uploaded to a worker type environment will call a URL/file that you set every 5 minutes (or whatever you enter in the schedule).